# Problem generating GeoTIFF from JPEG using GQIS Georeferencer tool

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, raster-conversion

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) to convert a JPEG image of a WGS-84 Web Mercator world map to a GeoTIFF file using QGIS, but am failing to do it correctly-- the map comes out with black-hole-like warping:

Original jpg:
[image]

Geotiff output (transformation type: inverse-spline):
[image]

I am inputting **EPSG:3857** coordinates using [this online tool](https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857), and in QGIS I set the Target SRS to **EPSG:3857**.

Here are some debugging steps I tried:

- Swap lon/lat values to lat/lon: did not fix, lon/lat seems correct
- Change transformation type to any of the other options (linear, projective, polynomial, etc): they all produce different types of skewing and warping
- Try adding more points, or spreading them around in different formations: did not fix, just changed the locations of the warp holes

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

I'm simply trying to generate a raster tileset for Mapbox, which requires a geotiff file, so if anyone would like to suggest any other free methods of doing this for a GIS-newbie, I'd love to hear them!

Edit:

Here's a screenshot of my georeferencer transformation settings:
[image]

Comment: Can you include a picture of the image that you are trying to georeference to?  Can you include a screen shot of the transformation setting in the QGIS georeferencer?

Comment: I'm trying to georeference to a mapbox map. So that's just like any interactive map you see online, for example the one embedded on this page: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/georeference-imagery/

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that the coordinates I'm adding to the georeferencer tool aren't exact-- I'm basically eyeing their positions then copypasting the resulting value from https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857 ...I figured a certain level of exactitude wasn't necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I've finally successfully generated a nice looking GeoTIFF file. I discovered [a slightly different tutorial outlining more-or-less the same QGIS process](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html) but with a little more detail describing what the `dX`, `dY` and `Residual` error values are, and how to adjust them. I adjusted the points I added to the JPG until all `dX` and `dY` error values were as close to `0` as possible. Then I generated the GeoTIFF file with Polynomial 2 transformation type and it came out fine.

So my suspected diagnosis is that I had too-high of error rates previously, although they must have not been very noticeable so it's best to be super precise.

Here is a screenshot showing the successful coordinates and error values:

[image]

Comment: You used originally Thin Plate Spline method that forces the residuals of all ground control points to be zero and image is warped exactly to every GCP . But if the GCPs are way off then the warped image can get really weird shapes as you noticed.

Comment: Thanks for that context, makes sense.